# In MPAndroidChart Line graph, Interested to show data set values outside of graph top side

Tags: android, graph, line, mpandroidchart, linechart

Please check this image, I interested to show chart like this. How can i do?

I need this

[image]
[image]

this my output, but need above chart result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, genereally this seems to be out of scope of MPAndroidChart features. You might as well show such data as Horizontal `RecyclerView` (with LinearLayoutManager's orientation as `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`).
Your ViewHolder item would just contain y-values from 2 data sets and presented in `TextView`'s.

I am glad you have created StackOverflow's question. Opening issue on library's github issue tracker seems redundant - it can be closed.